# Every time I want to pull a table on the SQL server, I have to write the path name prior

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to specify a path for every time I want to pull a table? Similar to how you would specify your Directory in R prior to use?  I am currently using the SQL on Visual Studio interface.  Thanks.

So I guess I don't know the proper syntax but prior to loading my table I always have to put in [server\user].tablename and I wanted to know if there is a way to always select from that [sever\user]. option because it's the same every time and gets redundant

Comment: What do you mean by path? Tables don't have a path. I assume you are querying tables that are not in your default schema? Assuming your default schema is dbo and you have a table in another schema you will have to list the schema. Alternately you could change your default schema.

Comment: I tried to clarify further

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. The only thing I can guess is that you are entering the schema for the tables. See my comment from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like working in SSMS.
Connect to SQL Server and all code will be executed there.
Use following code to work on a specific database and its tables:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
```

You should be able to just type the table name, without punctuation or anything preceding it.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats;
```